# python script hangs at results = sparql.query().convert()

Tags: python, sparql, mysql-python, dbpedia

In python, I am firing Sparql queries to get data from dbpedia.

At a point approximately firing 7,000 queries, my script is hangs at    line   results = sparql.query().convert()

which is already executed atleast 5000 times in the loop
Any idea what could be the issue in it

Answer (score 3):

try splitting up the .query() and .convert() into two separate lines. I would guess that .query() is where it's hanging, and I would further guess that you are being rate-limited by DBPedia, but I can't find any information on what their limits might be.

Comment: might be related with the query execution, so query(), or result parsing, so convert(), but I cannot really help with the information provided...